# Inequalities using logarithms

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Knowing that log(a) = b can be written as 10^b = a

How can I use that towards this inequality:

4/(x^2) <= log(n)

The logarithm is of base 10.

Comment: $$10^{4/x^2}\leq n\\ 10000^{x^{-2}}\leq n$$

Answer (score 0):

It works the same way. This is because $a \leq log(b) \implies 10^a \leq 10^{log(b)} \implies 10^a \leq b$. We can put both sides of the inequality to the power of $10$ because $10^x$ is an increasing function.

As for your equation, we have $10^{\frac{4}{x^2}} \leq n$.